# how i fix npm start error like "react-scripts"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I use ubuntu 20.04 and my node and npm versions like this:
~$ node -v
v18.17.1
~$ npm -v
9.6.7
when i run my project from terminal i have an this error:

> react-ros-robot@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

sh: 1: react-scripts: not found

i uninstall my nodejs and npm. and i reinstall it but still i have that issue.
i also while i was trying this solution have vulnerability errors:
[here is the video i use for fix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpUhY4VZd9M)

i tried also sudo npm install -g react-scripts
command and i have these warnings:

> npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
> npm WARN deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
> npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
> npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
> npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
> npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
> npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
> npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
> npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
> npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
> npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

Comment: please show your `package.json` file.

Comment: Did you try to install react-scripts globally?
`npm install -g react-scripts`

Comment: i'm using this code for learning you can check the package.json by this link: https://github.com/aniskoubaa/udemy-rosbridge-course

Comment: Try `npm run start` or `react-scripts start`.